# React-Redux - When calling an action I get TypeError: String.prototype.property called on null or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to implement Redux to control my navigation bar links dynamically. I have a 'link active' feature on the navigation bar links, that are active depending on what page is shown. Through all the links I have within the application that go to varying pages, it seems easier to handle what nav link is active or not with a Redux store.

I am getting this error: `TypeError: String.prototype.link called on null or undefined` when I call one of my actions that updates the store with what link should be active.

Here is my implementation starting with my action:

**navbar_actions.js**:

```
const Types = {
  NAV_LINK_ACTIVE: 'NAV_LINK_ACTIVE',
};

const navlinkActive = (link) => ({
  type: Types.NAV_LINK_ACTIVE,
  payload: link,
});

export default {
  navlinkActive,
  Types,
};
```

**navbar_reducers.js**:

```
import NAVBAR_ACTIONS from '../actions/navbar_actions';
import _ from 'lodash';

const defaultState = {
  link: '',
};

const navbarReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NAVBAR_ACTIONS.Types.NAV_LINK_ACTIVE: {
      let link = action.payload;
      return link;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default navbarReducer;
```

**store.js**:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import navbarReducer from '../reducers/navbar_reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(navbarReducer, initialState);
  return store;
}
```

Here is my Links component that the Navbar uses to render out links (this component just needs access to the store state) :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//Redux

import NAVBAR_ACTIONS from '../../../../modules/actions/navbar_actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import propTypes from 'prop-types';

//Styles
import { LinkContainer, LinkWrap } from './styles';

//Notes
//@Required: links array passed as props. Each object in the links array should contain a path and name property. Refer to propTypes definition at the bottom.

const Links = (props) => {
  const [clickedLink, setClickedLink] = useState('Home');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.link.length === 0) return;
    else setClickedLink(props.link);
  }, [props.link]);
  return (
    <LinkContainer>
      {props.links.map((link, i) => (
        <LinkWrap isActive={link.name === clickedLink ? true : false} key={i}>
          <Link
            to={link.path}
            onClick={() => {
              setClickedLink(link.name);
            }}
          >
            {link.name}
          </Link>
        </LinkWrap>
      ))}
    </LinkContainer>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  link: state.link,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Links);

Links.propTypes = {
  links: propTypes.arrayOf(
    propTypes.shape({
      path: propTypes.string.isRequired,
      name: propTypes.string.isRequired,
    })
  ).isRequired,
};
```

Via the `useEffect()` hook, anytime `props.link` updates, it will update that within the `Links` component state. This is how I think I would get the updated link from the `store` state every time it changes. Could be wrong, but this is my attempt.

This is the component that I call the action within:

```
import React from 'react';

//Redux
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import NAVBAR_ACTIONS from '../../../modules/actions/navbar_actions';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

//Styles
import {
  HomePageHero,
  LatestPostsHeader,
  HeroHeader,
  HeroText,
  HeroViewPosts,
} from './styles';

//Components
import Page from '../../Layout/Page';
import Blog from '../Blog/Blog';
import SocialLinks from './Components/SocialMediaLinks/SocialLinks';

const Home = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <Page noheader={true} pageTitle="">
      <HomePageHero>
        <HeroHeader>
          <p>Maison</p>
          <div></div>
          <p>Moa</p>
        </HeroHeader>
        <HeroText>
          <p>
            Loreum Ipsum 
          </p>
        </HeroText>
        <HeroViewPosts>
          <Link
            to="/blog"
            onClick={() => {
              props.navlinkActive('blog');
              console.log(props);
            }}
          >
            View My Blog
          </Link>
        </HeroViewPosts>
        <SocialLinks />
      </HomePageHero>
      <LatestPostsHeader>
        <h3>Latest Posts</h3>
      </LatestPostsHeader>
      <Blog pageTitle="Latest Posts" noheader={true} />
    </Page>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  navlinkActive: (link) => dispatch(NAVBAR_ACTIONS.navlinkActive(link)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

This is an actual screen shot of the error I get when calling `props.navlinkActive()`:

[image]

I am at a bit of a loss here on this error as I couldn't really find anything 'Redux' specific regarding it. Thanks for the help and insight in advance!

Comment: Is it `props.link` or `props.links`? I don't get how you could end up with the deprecated `String.prototype.link` method anywhere though, `props` is not a string right?

Comment: @Bergi It’s props.link for the actual link in the stores state. If you look at the default state of the reducer, the default is an empty string. Maybe that could be the issue?

Comment: @Bergi from some more digging, it appears that the issue is because my `Links` component isn't getting the updated `link` prop from the store. Through some `console.logs` I checked my action and reducer and they are working as expected and the state is updating. However, when this store state updates, my `Links` component doesn't get the new props, so my Navbar doesn't re-render with the new props. Can't figure out why this is the case. `useEffect(() => {}, [props.link])` should cause a re-render when that value changes, but that value update is not reaching `Links.js` as I thought.

Comment: @Bergi solved, thanks for the initial comment.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this issue. The error was coming from my `Links.js` component:

Specifically this here:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.link.length === 0) return;
    else setClickedLink(props.link);
  }, [props.link]);
```

`props.link` was undefined. This was because I was not returning the store state properly from `navbar_reducer.js`.

This is how the reducer should of been returning state (using lodash `cloneDeep()` here):

```
const navbarReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NAVBAR_ACTIONS.Types.NAV_LINK_ACTIVE: {
      let link = action.payload;
      let newState = _.cloneDeep(state);
      newState.link = link;
      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

The old way. I was modifying the existing state in the reducer instead of returning a new copy of state with the necessary change(s). ***I was mutating the existing state directly, and in doing so, Redux does not detect a change, therefore any component using `connect()` to get access to the store, never gets an update.***

All is working as expected now. It's rule #1 in React. DO NOT MUTATE STATE! I should of known. Make sure you are always getting a deep copy of state and then making changes to that copy.